# array combine is not working in php?

Tags: php, arrays

my code is:

array set 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15-3
    [1] => 16-3
    [2] => 15-4
    [3] => 16-4
    [4] => 15-3
    [5] => 16-3
    [6] => 15-4
    [7] => 16-4
    [8] => 15-3
    [9] => 16-3
    [10] => 15-4
    [11] => 16-4
)
```

My second array set is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 3
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 3
)
```

i just combine the above both the two array into one like below

```
$data1=array_combine($store_attri_ids, $store_ids);
```

but its shows like that

```
Array
(
    [15-3] => 3
    [16-3] => 3
    [15-4] => 3
    [16-4] => 3
)
```

The remaining values are not combined, wt we do nw????

Comment: Where *is* your code?

Comment: You can't have same index multiple times.

Comment: You can't have the same key twice!

Comment: But you can have sub-arrays.

Comment: then how can i combine or merge the above two array into one

Comment: @KarnaGowtham Either put each key => value pair into a subArray, or put all values with the same key into an array as value.

Comment: You cannot have an associative array with duplicate keys. It would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by creating a sub-array -

```
$data1 = array();
foreach($store_attri_ids as $key => $id) {
    $data1[$id][] = $store_ids[$key];
}
```

The output would be like -

```
Array
(
    [15-3] => array(1, 2, 3),
    [16-3] => array(...),
    [15-4] => array(...),
    [16-4] => array(...)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use array_combine the result is totally correct, like putting here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

You need use array_merge, take a look at the documentation :http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$data1=array_merge($store_attri_ids, $store_ids);

print_r($data1);
```

Comment: array merge is differ from array_combine

Comment: $keys   = array('u1','u2','u3');
$names  = array('Bob','Fred','Joe');
$emails = array('bob@mail.com','fred@mail.com','joe@mail.com');
$ids    = array(1,2,3);
$result = array();

foreach ($keys as $id => $key) {
    $result[$key] = array(
        'name'  => $names[$id],
        'email' => $emails[$id],
        'id'    => $ids[$id],
    );
}